# Загрузка изображения по URL в Django проект

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я хочу загрузить изображение по URL-адресу, но в модели сохраняется только сам URL-адрес, как я могу указать путь для сохранения в папку media и как его вообще сохранить?

Код:

```
from django.db import models
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse

upload_path = 'media/'

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, null= True, blank=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

    def get_image(self):
        name = urlparse(str(self.image)).path.split('/')[-1]
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(str(self.image_url), 'img\media\media' + name + '.jpg')
```